# MVVMCross iOS: how to bind a command with Custom transition when switching to different View model

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

For MVVMCross ios, how can I use different TransitionalStyle such as FlipHorizontal style instead of the default sliding effect with "ShowViewModel"?

```
[Register("SearchResults")]
public class SearchResultsView : MvxTableViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        Title = "List";
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var mapButton = new UIButton(new RectangleF(0, 0, 65, 30));
        mapButton.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle("images/map_btn.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
        mapButton.TouchUpInside += MapButtonClicked();
        var rightButton = new UIBarButtonItem(mapButton);
        NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

        var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<SearchResultsView, SearchResultsViewModel>();
        //bindings.Bind(mapButton).To(x => x.ShowMapCommand); //how to do with binding command?
        bindings.Apply();
    }

    private EventHandler MapButtonClicked()
    {
        return (sender, args) =>
        {

            var mapView = new SearchResultMapView {ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal};
            var navigationController = new UINavigationController(mapView);
            PresentViewController(navigationController, true, null);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ViewModels/Views are presented using a Presenter.

For Modal displays of navigation controllers, some people use the [MvxModalNavSupportTouchViewPresenter.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxModalNavSupportTouchViewPresenter.cs)

You can use this presenter by overriding `CreatePresenter` in Setup:

```
    protected override IMvxTouchViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
    {
        return new MvxModalNavSupportTouchViewPresenter(ApplicationDelegate, Window);
    }
```

With this done then you should be able to achieve your transition effect by adding `IMvxModalTouchView` inheritance and by setting `ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal;` in the constructor for your `SearchResultMapView`.

```
    public class SearchResultMapView 
         : MvxViewController, IMvxModalTouchView
    {
        public SearchResultMapView()
        {
            ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal;
        }

        // more code here....
    }
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to completely customise the presentation of the view/viewcontroller, then implementing a custom presenter is fairly straight-forward to do - for more information, see some of the articles and tutorials on custom presenters in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/presenter-roundup.html

Comment: It worked. But how can I have a close button on the screen and press it to flip map view back to previous screen? I tried to set DismissViewController on this close button's TouchUpInside event. However, I got this error when click the second time: Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Only one modal view controller at a time supported

Answer (score 0):

@wing

All you need to do is add a close button to the new view of the pushed view controller and override it's touchupinside as follows:

```
private void CloseBtnTouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
            DismissModalViewController(false);
}
```