# MvvmCross ViewModel transition from the left

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing an app for iOS using MvvmCross.  On one of my Views I have some basic report data that is displayed in a tableview.

When the table row is touched a new view containing a detail report is displayed by making the call to ShowViewModel passing some parameters in a Dictionary.  This works fine.

When the user swipes left or right the app needs to show the detail report for the next or previous item in the original list.  I am doing this by updating some parameters and calling ShowViewModel again.  The logic behind this is all working fine.

My problem;  ShowViewModel animates the new view coming in from the right.  This is perfect when the user has swiped left.  However when swiping right it seems counter intuitive.  How can I make ShowViewModel animate or transition in from the left side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I was able to come up with following the helpful pointers in the answer from Andrei N. In the end I opted for a TransitionFlipFromRight and TransitionFlipFromLeft when scrolling between detail reports.  Hopefully it is useful to somebody else.

I already had a presenter class that was inherited from MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter

```
public class BedfordViewPresenter : MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter
```

Within this class I added a property of MvxPresentationHint.

```
private MvxPresentationHint _presentationHint;
```

In the override of method ChangePresentation the above property is used to store the passed in parameter

```
    public override void ChangePresentation (MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        _presentationHint = hint;
        base.ChangePresentation (hint);
    }
```

Two new MvxPresentationHint class were declared (see later)

In the presenter class the Show method was overridden

```
    public override void Show(IMvxTouchView view)
    {
        if (_presentationHint is FlipFromRightPresentationHint) {
            var viewController = view as UIViewController;
            MasterNavigationController.PushControllerWithTransition (viewController, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight);

        }
        else
            if (_presentationHint is FlipFromLeftPresentationHint)  {
                var viewController = view as UIViewController;
                MasterNavigationController.PushControllerWithTransition (viewController, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft);
            }
            else {
                base.Show (view);
            }

        _presentationHint = null;
    }
```

A new class that provides extensions to a UINavigationController was created with the method PushControllerWithTransition

```
public static class UINavigationControllerExtensions
{
    public static void PushControllerWithTransition(this UINavigationController 
        target, UIViewController controllerToPush, 
        UIViewAnimationOptions transition)
    {
        UIView.Transition(target.View, 0.75d, transition, delegate() {
            target.PushViewController(controllerToPush, false);
        }, null);
    }
}
```

All that needs to be defined now are the two new MvxPresentationHint class derivations.  These belong in your Core class library project rather than the iOS application project.

```
public class FlipFromLeftPresentationHint : MvxPresentationHint
{
    public FlipFromLeftPresentationHint ()
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FlipFromRightPresentationHint: MvxPresentationHint
{
    public FlipFromRightPresentationHint ()
    {
    }
}
```

I hope this is a help to someone else trying to do something similar

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @JDibble. I am trying to create a simple sliding transition from left to right. Do you know if this is possible using UIViewAnimationOptions?

Answer (score 2):

if you look to the MvvmCross source code [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bbf9a2ac76e74d9404f4b57036c6e29dfe2cc6c3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxTouchViewPresenter.cs#L74) you see how the default behavior is showing the ViewControllers

You need to change that by doing something like the following:
[How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app)

for that, one idea is to have a custom view presenter and catch navigation to that particular view-model (override Show(IMvxTouchView view) )

or, maybe derive from UINavigationController, set it to MvvmCross to use it (look to the MvxSetup), and on some events change transition to that particular view

similar to this question
[How to specify view transitions on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860155/how-to-specify-view-transitions-on-iphone)

Comment: Andrei,  thanks for your help, you highlighted areas that I investigated and was able to create a working solution.  In the end I opted for a TransitionFlipFromRight and TransitionFlipFromLeft when scrolling between detail reports.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Share my solution for android:

On view:

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var layout = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.swippeable);

        var swipeListener = new SwipeListener(this.Activity);

        swipeListener.OnSwipeLeft += (sender, e) => this.ViewModel.LeftCommand?.Execute(); //Here use command into view model

        swipeListener.OnSwipeRight += (sender, e) => this.ViewModel.RightCommand?.Execute();

        layout.SetOnTouchListener(swipeListener);

        return view;
    }
```

Gesture listener:

```
public class SwipeListener : SimpleOnGestureListener, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    private const int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private const int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    private readonly GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public SwipeListener(Context ctx)
    {
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, this);
    }

    public Boolean OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        return this.gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
    }

    public event EventHandler OnSwipeRight;

    public event EventHandler OnSwipeLeft;

    public event EventHandler OnSwipeTop;

    public event EventHandler OnSwipeBottom;

    public override Boolean OnDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Boolean OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        Boolean result = false;

        float diffY = e2.GetY() - e1.GetY();

        float diffX = e2.GetX() - e1.GetX();

        if (Math.Abs(diffX) > Math.Abs(diffY))
        {
            if (Math.Abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.Abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
            {
                if (diffX > 0)
                {
                    SwipeRight();
                }
                else
                {
                    SwipeLeft();
                }
                result = true;
            }
        }
        else if (Math.Abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.Abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
        {
            if (diffY > 0)
            {
                SwipeBottom();
            }
            else
            {
                SwipeTop();
            }
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void SwipeRight()
    {
        this.OnSwipeRight?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void SwipeLeft()
    {
        this.OnSwipeLeft?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void SwipeTop()
    {
        this.OnSwipeTop?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void SwipeBottom()
    {
        this.OnSwipeBottom?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works and should be accepted as the answer.