# Transition from left to right

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

When navigating between views the transition is represented as a sliding from right to left using MVVMCross by calling

```
ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>();
```

Is there a way to change the transition to slide from left to right or top to bottom?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which platform, I assume it's iOS.
Does this help:

[MvvmCross ViewModel transition from the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296840/mvvmcross-viewmodel-transition-from-the-left/26302321)

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this. Unfortunately UIViewAnimationOptions does not support sliding which is strange since sliding is quite common for transitions.