# How to transit to another view from right side, instead of the default transition(appears from the bottom)?

Tags: ios, swift2

The default transition from one view to another is that the new view appears from the bottom. How can I change it so that the new view appears from the right side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MvvmCross ViewModel transition from the left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296840/mvvmcross-viewmodel-transition-from-the-left)

Comment: I think we asked different things, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `UINavigationController`.

The easiest way to do that is to select your starting view controller on the storyboard and then, on the menu, choose `Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller`.

At that point, your segues of type `Show` will do a push animation.

Comment: Thanks!! "Embed In" really works fine :D I'll go check out uinavigationcontroller